# Valid JSON, but can't display elements of array

Tags: php, jquery, arrays, json, multidimensional-array

I've been working on this for quite a while, and I've read ***TONS*** of posts on SO trying to figure out how I need to do this, and I can't seem to get it to work.  I'm thinking it must be some aspect of the way I've coded things. So downvote away, but hopefully some kind soul will help me out.

I've tested using jsonlint, which comes back valid.  I'm getting a response from the server with the values, I just can't seem to get anything in the browser other than when I just alert(response);.  I need to be able to access the value of "cat_id_PK" and the other elements separately to loop through and display them in html table cells.

**JSON:**

```
{
"income": [
    {
        "cat_id_PK": 14,
        "cat_name": "test1",
        "cat_amount": "100.00"
    },
    {
        "cat_id_PK": 15,
        "cat_name": "test2",
        "cat_amount": "200.00"
    },
    {
        "cat_id_PK": 34,
        "cat_name": "test3",
        "cat_amount": "300.00"
    },
"expense": [
    {
        "cat_id_PK": 14,
        "cat_name": "tes41",
        "cat_amount": "400.00"
    },
    {
        "cat_id_PK": 15,
        "cat_name": "test5",
        "cat_amount": "500.00"
    },
    {
        "cat_id_PK": 34,
        "cat_name": "test6",
        "cat_amount": "600.00"
    }
]
}
```

**PHP**

```
    $array = array(
        'income'    => $income,
        'expense'   => $expense,
        'recurring' => $recurring
    );

    echo json_encode($array);
```

**JQUERY**

```
var request = $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: 'inc/functions.php',
dataType: "JSON",
    data: {action: "display_categories", cur_month:cur_month}
});
request.done(function(response){
     //for each element put values in <td></td> tags.
});
```

Comment: where do you access your json response? from `.success()` or `.done()`?

Comment: Show us the entire ajax call, and what dataType you're using.

Comment: Have you set `dataType` to `'json'` in your jQuery AJAX request? If not you might have a text string instead of an array.

Comment: I edited to include the rest of my AJAX call.

Comment: @John S - I copied the JSON from my developer tools window into jsonlint, and then into here...its not hard-coded

Comment: one thing I did notice, and I'm not sure if it matters, but if I just alert response[0], it will return just the first character of the JSON array.  If I alert response[1], it alerts the next character, and so on....this makes me think its a text string..

Comment: @Drixson Oseña - I access the json response from request.done().

Comment: Notwithstanding your comments above, your JSON data fails validation at jsonlint.com

Comment: I've been updating a lot of code trying to combine ajax requests, and I actually was missing the datatype on this one, but even after adding it in, no matter what I try, I'm getting [Object:Object] or undefined.  I'm literally doing nothing more than alert(response);

Comment: _" but if I just alert response[0], it will return just the first character of the JSON array."_ - Yes, that's because `response` is a string - the raw string containing JSON, where what you want is to parse that string to get an object. jQuery does this automatically once you add `dataType:"json"`, in which case seeing `[object Object]` in your alert is _correct_.

Comment: However, I'm still left with the same problem, which is that I'm not sure how to access response -> income -> the value of cat_id_PK. Should it be "response.income.value"  I tried response.income.length, and that returns a number, but anything else is either [Object:Object] or undefined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *"I've tested using jsonlint, which comes back valid."*

No it doesn't, not for the JSON you've shown which has an error: it is missing a closing `]` after the `}` and before the comma on the line before `"expense" : ...`. But perhaps that's just a typo in your question given that you're generating the JSON with `json_encode()` (which wouldn't produce an error like that).

> *" I just can't seem to get anything in the browser other than when I just `alert(response);`"*

So you are getting a value of some sort back then.

> *" but if I just alert `response[0]`, it will return just the first character of the JSON array."*

Yes, that's because `response` is a string - the raw string containing JSON, where what you want is to parse that string to get an object. Except that you don't have to do this manually because jQuery will do it automatically once you add `dataType:"json"` to your `$.ajax()` options.

> *"I actually was missing the datatype on this one, but even after adding it in, no matter what I try, I'm getting `[Object:Object]` or undefined. I'm literally doing nothing more than `alert(response);`"*

Once you add the `dataType:"json"` the `response` parameter will be an object, which when you try to alert will correctly display as `[object Object]`. If you use `console.log(response)` then in your browser's console you'd see the actual object. You'd get `undefined` if you try to access a property that doesn't exist.

> *"I need to be able to access the value of `cat_id_PK` and the other elements separately to loop through and display them in html table cells."*

Your `response` object has two properties, `income` and `expenses`, both of which are arrays of object. So use `response.income` to access the first array of objects, and `response.expenses` to access the second array of objects. The first income item is `response.income[0]` and the property you asked about is `response.income[0].cat_id_PK`. So you can use a `for` loop, or use `$.each()` to iterate over the array and do something with each `.cat_id_PK` property:

```
var request = $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: 'inc/functions.php',
    dataType: "json",
    data: {action: "display_categories", cur_month:cur_month}
});
request.done(function(response){
  //for each element put values in <td></td> tags.
  var tr = $("<tr></tr>");
  // using traditional for loop for income items
  for(var i = 0; i < response.income.length; i++) {
    $("<td></td>").text(response.income[i].cat_id_PK).appendTo(tr);
  }
  tr.appendTo("#idOfTableHere");
  var tr = $("<tr></tr>");
  // use equivalent jQuery $.each for expense items
  $.each(response.expenses, function(i, v) {
    $("<td></td>").text(v.cat_id_PK).appendTo(tr);
  });
  tr.appendTo("#idOfTableHere");
});
```

The code I've shown creates new td elements in each loop, appending them to new table rows, and then after each loop the new row is appended to a table that I've assumed already exists on your page with `id="idOfTableHere"`.

Comment: Great answer, and thorough solution that I understand way more than all the SO posts I've read on this subject.  THANK YOU!!!  One thing I'm not sure of in incorporating your code is, I'd like to set the cat_id_PK as the id on the <td> elements.  I'm trying to work out how I would do that with you solution above.

Comment: `$("<td id='" + response.income[i].cat_id_PK + "'></td>").text("some text here").etc...` or `$("<td></td>", { id : response.income[i].cat_id_PK }).etc...` should do it.

Answer (score 0):

**try this you miss dataType:**

```
var request = $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: 'inc/functions.php',
    data: {action: "display_categories", cur_month:cur_month},
    dataType:"json",
});
request.done(function(response){
     //for each element put values in <td></td> tags.
});
```